# Gunicorn is creating workers in every second

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I am running Django using Gunicorn behind Nginx. In one of my installation, when I run the gunicorn process, I keep getting debug output, it's like workers are being created in every second (I assume this because django is loading very slow and note the message "[20205] [DEBUG] 3 workers"). You can check the detail output at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/bahar/98afe587351d29d12320)
In similar setup, I am running 3 more installations without any such issues and respective site loads almost instantly.
Any idea why this is happening? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The polling of the workers every second on `--log-level debug` was introduced in `gunicorn==19.2`.

Change the log level to info.